# How to modify a Rails engine to require my library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

I have a Rails engine (someone else's gem) that I am trying to modify by adding another gem as a dependency. I can't seem to figure out how to get the engine to require the library. I've tried all sorts of different things, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My main app Gemfile I have the engine:

```
gem 'enginegem'
```

In the engine's gemspec I have:

```
s.add_dependency 'somethinggem', '~> 1.0'
```

In the Engine, there is a model that I am trying to modify by adding this `acts_as_something` method:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_something
end
```

And there is a controller that I am trying to modify:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :do_something

  def do_something
    my_var = 'foobar'
    Something.do_something_with my_var do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

What is the appropriate way to add this library as a dependency to the engine and have it require the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd help if you told us which gem you're trying to modify.

In most gems you will have a lib/enginegem.rb, there is probably the best place to require the gem:

```
require 'somethinggem'
```

**EDIT: Although this answer didn't help the OP (see comments below), I'll keep it here, because it may help others.**

**EDIT 2: Everybody who is trying to create an engine should take a look at [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb)'s code. If you want a more didactic approach, try [Crafting Rails Applications](http://pragprog.com/titles/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications) book from Jose Valim. In fact, if you're serious with this engine, you should do both.**

Comment: Could you try to include the require in the model, instead? Tell me if it works so I can update the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you're requiring the lib correctly? Some gems are required with a different name.

Comment: i got it to work. didn't have anything to do with what I was doing. something wrong with the actual gem i was using.

Comment: That's ok. I'll keep the answer here, cause it may help others.

Comment: How did you got it to work? Is it possible to require a gem in your gem? E.g i'm building a Rails::Engine and i want to include CKEditor and kanimari. Is this possible if i do it this way?

Comment: Yep, the common practice is to require other gems in `lib/<enginename>.rb`.

Comment: @PabloB. is right about how to require other gems, but this specific case is about someone who's written their own Rails engine but it isn't being required. This wouldn't work since isn't loaded anyway.